# How to populate table rows, using a [String] array sent from iPhone by Watch Connectivity?

Tags: swift, watchkit, watchos-2, watchconnectivity

Basically, it's passing the array fine.  It's just when trying to use the enumerated array as the tablerows, it says nil found.

PHONE

```
import UIKit
import WatchConnectivity

class ViewController: UIViewController, WCSessionDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var sendButton: UIButton!

    var watchSession: WCSession?
    var arrayCustom = ["thing1", "thing2"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if(WCSession.isSupported()) {
            watchSession = WCSession.defaultSession()
            watchSession?.delegate = self
            watchSession?.activateSession()
        }

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }


    @IBAction func sendArray(sender: AnyObject) {
        sendToWatch()

    }


    private func sendToWatch() {
        do {
            let applicationDict = ["Array1": arrayCustom]
            try WCSession.defaultSession().updateApplicationContext(applicationDict)
        }

        catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

WATCHKIT

```
private func loadThCust() {

        if (WCSession.isSupported()) {
            watchSession = WCSession.defaultSession()
            watchSession.delegate = self;
            watchSession.activateSession()]
        }

func session(session: WCSession, didReceiveApplicationContext applicationContext: [String : AnyObject]) {

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { () -> Void in

            if let retrievedArray1 = applicationContext["Array1"] as? [String] {
                self.custArray = retrievedArray1
                print(self.custArray)
            }
            for (index, thName) in self.custArray.enumerate() {
                let row2 = self.choiceTable.rowControllerAtIndex(index) as! ChoiceTableRowController
                row2.choiceLabel.setText(thName)
                }
            }
        }
```

My problem is I'm getting this console output + error whenever I try and load the TableView:

```
["thing1", "thing2"]
2016-02-24 03:21:25.912 WristaRoo WatchKit Extension[9401:243561] Error - attempt to ask for row 0. Valid range is 0..0
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

Does anyone have any idea why the unwrapped value is still nil? I was hoping that once I get it set and can see that there are values in the [String] array, it could enumerate it, but it seems like they are just invisible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You started the question with the statement, "Basically, It's passing the array fine" so it's not a Watch Connectivity issue.

You simply didn't specify the number of rows for `choiceTable` before iterating through your array.

```
choiceTable.setNumberOfRows(custArray.count, withRowType: "ChoiceTableRowController")
```

**Determining the problem from the console output:**

- Error - attempt to ask for row 0. Valid range is 0..0

  [`rowControllerAtIndex:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceTable_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/WKInterfaceTable/rowControllerAtIndex:) returns (an Optional which is) nil when its index is out of bounds.

  > The row controller object, or nil if there are no row controllers yet or index is out of bounds.

  You tried to access a row which didn't exist, leading to a bounds warning.
- fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

  ```
  row2.choiceLabel.setText(thName)
  ```

  `row2` is nil.

You should be able to easily track down bugs like this in the debugger. If you examined `row2` and saw that it was nil, you'd realize that the problem wasn't with the array itself, but that the table has no rows.

Comment: ugh, thank you for tis - coding at 3am isn't always the best option. it tok me all of 5 minutes to add in
`self.choiceTable.setNumberOfRows(self.custArray.count, withRowType: "ChoiceTableRowController")`
to get it working