# WatchConnectivity, How to Share an Array between iPhone and Apple Watch

Tags: arrays, watchkit, swift4, watchconnectivity

I am attempting to pass an array between iPhone and Apple Watch Apps in Swift 4, thus far I have been unsuccessful. Here are a few examples I have tried to follow, unsuccessfully. In those examples they don't include many of the functions, however when I try and write it like that it gives the error `does not conform to protocols` in addition when I declare the watch session It doesn't declare properly, also the `didRecieveApplicationContext` is very different in swift 4 than as shown in the other questions/ examples [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35596888/how-to-populate-table-rows-using-a-string-array-sent-from-iphone-by-watch-con) [Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27025526/passing-data-to-apple-watch-app/35022352#35022352)

Here is my iPhone ViewController

```
import UIKit
import WatchConnectivity

class watchtimetablemaker: UIViewController, WCSessionDelegate {

func session(_ session: WCSession, activationDidCompleteWith activationState: WCSessionActivationState, error: Error?) {
}

func sessionDidBecomeInactive(_ session: WCSession) {
}

func sessionDidDeactivate(_ session: WCSession) {
}


var watchSession: WCSession?
var initalArray = [String]()
var combination = ""
var vdlArray = [String]()


@IBAction func Save(_ sender: Any) {

    vdlArray.removeAll()

//here I edit the arrays, add instances etc. cut out for fluency

    self.view.endEditing(true)

    sendToWatch()

    UserDefaults.standard.set(vdlArray, forKey: "vdlarray")
    UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()

    print(initalArray)
    print(vdlArray)

}

func sendToWatch(){
    do{
        let appDictionary = ["Array": initalArray]
        try WCSession.default.updateApplicationContext(appDictionary)
    }
    catch {
        print(error)
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if (WCSession.isSupported()){
        watchSession = WCSession.default
        watchSession?.delegate = self
        watchSession?.activate()
    }

    vdlArray = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "vdlarray") as! [String]

    print(vdlArray)

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}
}
```

Here is the Apple Watch Controller

```
import WatchKit
import Foundation
import WatchConnectivity


class TimetableWatch: WKInterfaceController, WCSessionDelegate {

func session(_ session: WCSession, activationDidCompleteWith activationState: WCSessionActivationState, error: Error?) {
    load()
}

@IBOutlet var tabletitle: WKInterfaceTable!
var watchSession: WCSession?
var tableData = [String]()

override func awake(withContext context: Any?) {
    super.awake(withContext: context)

    if (WCSession.isSupported()){
        watchSession = WCSession.default
        watchSession?.delegate = self
        watchSession?.activate()
    }

    load()

    tabletitle.setNumberOfRows(tableData.count, withRowType: "Cell")

    var i = 0
    for item in tableData {
        let row = tabletitle.rowController(at: i) as! TableCellRow

        row.tbalecelllabel.setText(item)

        i = i + 1
    }
}

func load(){

    func session(session: WCSession, didRecieveApplicationContext applicationContext: [String : Any]) {

        DispatchQueue.main.async() { () -> Void in
            if let retreivedArray = applicationContext["Array"] as? [String] {
                self.tableData = retreivedArray
                print(self.tableData)
            }
        }
    }
}

override func willActivate() {
    super.willActivate()
}

override func didDeactivate() {
    super.didDeactivate()
}
}
```

I have been unable to find any documentation relating to swift4 so, any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I haven't been using Swift 4 (yet), but it looks odd that your didReceiveApplicationContext function is wrapped in the load() function.  And you can declare the WCSession like:  let session = WCSession.default()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `WKInterfaceController`:

I agree with the comment from Jens Peter that you shouldn't wrap `didReceiveApplicationContext` in the load() function.

Handle errors in `activationDidCompleteWith` as such:

```
func session(_ session: WCSession, activationDidCompleteWith activationState: WCSessionActivationState, error: Error?) {
    if let error = error {
        print("Activation failed with error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        return
    }
    print("Watch activated with state: \(activationState.rawValue)")
}
```

That will also help determine if `WatchConnectivity` is even becoming established.

Remove `var watchSession: WCSession?` completely and declare `WCSession` in `awake(withContext)` as:

```
if WCSession.isSupported() {
        let watchSession = WCSession.default
        watchSession = self
        watchSession()
    }
```

Also remove the call to `load()` in `awake(withContext)`.

In `InterfaceController` it's helpful to put some `print` statements in your WCSession stubs even if you're not entirely using them. You can see if WatchConnectivity is activating.

```
func sessionDidBecomeInactive(_ session: WCSession) {
    // To support multiple watches.
    print("WC Session did become inactive.")
}

func sessionDidDeactivate(_ session: WCSession) {
    // To support multiple watches.
    WCSession.default.activate()
    print("WC Session did deactivate.")
}

func session(_ session: WCSession, activationDidCompleteWith activationState: WCSessionActivationState, error: Error?) {
    if let error = error {
        print("WC Session activation failed with error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        return
    }
    print("Phone activated with state: \(activationState.rawValue)")
}
```

This line `WCSession.default.activate()` as you see in `sessionDidDeactivate` will allow for multiple watch support in the off case the user happens to have more than one watch.

Remove the `var watchSession: WCSession?` as you did in `WKInterfaceController`. Once again in `viewDidLoad()` check for `WCSession` support with:

```
if WCSession.isSupported() {
        let watchSession = WCSession.default
        watchSession = self
        watchSession()
    }
```

Update `sendToWatch()` to:

```
func sendToWatch() {
let session = WCSession.default()

if session.activationState == .activated {
    let appDictionary = ["Array": initalArray]
do { 
    try session.updateApplicationContext(appDictionary)
} catch {
    print(error)
  }
 }  
}
```

I think that cleans it up a bit and will hopefully work or at least move you forward. I didn't build this in a project however. Hope this helps.